# Remove space between text and line(Python)

Tags: python

```py
import requests
import bs4

r = requests.get('http://books.toscrape.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
titles = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'nav nav-list'})

for title in titles:
    print(title.text.strip())
```

My results is:

```
 Books






                                Travel






                                Mystery






                                Historical Fiction






                                Sequential Art






                                Classics






                                Philosophy






                                Romance






                                Womens Fiction






                                Fiction






                                Childrens






                                Religion






                                Nonfiction






                                Music






                                Default






                                Science Fiction






                                Sports and Games






                                Add a comment






                                Fantasy






                                New Adult






                                Young Adult
```

But I really want the result without those huge indentations and spaces between each title. Can somebody help?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried inspecting the titles to see where the whitespace is coming from?

Comment: Thank for the response. When i inspected my data, the text shown as "                         Book                         ' when a lot of spaces between the title. Is that mean the spaces are unremovable? Thank again

Comment: _Is that mean the spaces are unremovable?_ That shouldn’t be a thing. Can you share the list in your post? Just `print(titles)`, or `repr(titles)` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
line = title.text.strip()
if line:
  print(line)
```

when we do this, we ignore blank lines

Comment: Thank for the response. I tried your method, but the result is the same. When I inspected my data, its shown as the follow: "                                       Book                                      " Is that mean the space is unremovable?